# bash pgrep weird command output

Tags: bash

I have following in my script

```
ACTIVE="$(pgrep -a crawl | wc -l)"
echo $ACTIVE
pgrep -a crawl | wc -l
```

echo is giving me 3, and last line is giving me 2.

Does anyone knows why?

Thank you

Comment: This happens consistently? You can run this more than once in a row and get those results each time? This isn't just a temporary process that died/finished between the two calls in whatever run of this you saw it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the script is called 'crawl'.  In that case, the higher number in $ACTIVE is due to the additional process that runs the command inside $(...).  I'd expect the numbers to be 2 and 1 instead of 3 and 2 though.  There must be another process called 'crawl' on the system when the script is running.